# How to read input string with spaces of certain length from text file c++

Tags: c++

My problem is that I am trying to input char, string then int from a text file. I know how to input using getline(), however after using the get line() function there is no longer an option to input the rest of the integers following the string. My question is, how can I input a char, then a string (with spaces) followed by 3 ints?

data.txt looks like this

```
a   New York    5    7   9
b   Virginia    10   2   5
c   Los Angeles 25   15  6
```

Here is my code:

```
   int main()
   {
    string city;
    double price;
    int amt1, amt2, amt3;
    char orderStatus;

    ifstream warehouse;
    ofstream output;
    warehouse.open("data.txt");
    output.open("dataOut.txt");

    while (warehouse.good()) 
    {
        warehouse >> orderStatus;
        output << orderStatus << "\t";

        getline(warehouse, city, '\t');
        //warehouse >> city;
        output << city << endl;

        //warehouse >> amt1;
        //output << amt1 << "\t";

        //warehouse >> amt2;
        //output << amt2 << "\t";

        //warehouse >> amt3;
        //output << amt3;
    }


    warehouse.close();
    output.close();

    return 0;
   }
```

Thanks for your much need help.

Comment: One way would be, after getting line, tokenize the string.

Comment: Agreed with @Mahesh. Did that several times before like that. The problem is that your "int" is an ASCII character when it comes from a text file. This means it is actually rather a char/string which needs to be converted to an int.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to use [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) (link to docs). This sounds like homework so I don't want to solve it for you (where's the fun in that?) but you could pull the values in as strings. If you wanted you could also manually convert characters to integers one at a time and reconstruct the numbers but `atoi` would handle it all. I'm guessing these are std::string, so you'll have to call [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) on them as atoi only accepts C strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my edit on your code. I added a `warehouse >> noskipws >> orderStatus >> skipws;` to skip the first tab delimiter. Also, added a `if(!warehouse.good()) break;` after every read in case there is incomplete data. If it were C, I'd have done `fscanf(file, " %c %[^\t]s %d %d %d", ...)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string city;
    double price;
    int amt1, amt2, amt3;
    char orderStatus;

    ifstream warehouse;
    ofstream output;
    warehouse.open("data.txt");
    output.open("dataOut.txt");

    while (warehouse.good()) 
    {
        warehouse >> orderStatus; 
        if(!warehouse.good()) break;
        output << orderStatus << "\t";
        // to skip the tab delimiter
        warehouse >> noskipws >> orderStatus >> skipws;
        if(!warehouse.good()) break;

        getline(warehouse, city, '\t');
        if(!warehouse.good()) break;
        output << city << "\t";

        warehouse >> amt1;
        if(!warehouse.good()) break;
        output << amt1 << "\t";

        warehouse >> amt2;
        if(!warehouse.good()) break;
        output << amt2 << "\t";

        warehouse >> amt3;
        if(!warehouse.good()) break;
        output << amt3 << endl;
    }


    warehouse.close();
    output.close();

    return 0;
}
```